# bookdown cross-reference links pointing below figures

Tags: hyperlink, figure, bookdown, cross-reference

In reports generated using bookdown, when clicking the cross-reference hyperlinks pointing toward figures, it brings me below the figure so I end up only having the caption of the Figure at the top of my screen and I need to scroll up to see the Figure.

This problem only occurs when using a web browser to view the generated output. It does not occur with RStudio integrated viewer for which the whole Figure is correctly displayed on my screen.

This happens with any bookdown html generated output, even with the unmodified bookdown demo files.

Any clue about what may cause this behavior ?

Edit : The problem seems to be browser-related. It occurs with both Chrome and Edge, but not with Firefox, Safari (thanks jtbayly) or Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't see this happening in the demo book using Safari on a Mac. Here is a link to the figure in the demo book:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/intro.html#fig:nice-fig

Does that produce the same result for you?

Comment: I tried it with both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported on Github also https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1155 and this is fixed in next version of bookdown (0.23)

For now only a dev version

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/bookdown")
```